How can we improve this motion detected ambient light sensor circuit?

It's a motion detected ambient light sensor (although we haven't gotten to the motion part).
We also have issues towards supplying enough volts towards potentiometer through output of comparator 2 since it's also connected to the relay with a diode in between.

Welcome! Your schematic is hard to read. Please have the signal flow from left to right and no 90 degrees rotated parts. How do you achieve hysteresis with this circuit so it doesn't flash on-off just around the threshold voltage of your comparator?

Razzledazzle - Hi, Is that schematic your own work, or copied / adapted from somewhere? TY

The comments already give a relatively nice insight into what's bad with your schematic, and since the schematic's quality will have influence on the quality with which you can lay out the circuit, that's quality feedback on the circuit.
So,

signal flow should be left to right
component ports should be ordered by functionality, not by pin number,
only negative supplies and ground point down; +3V and 7V should point up!
don't crowd your circuit; it's hard to read if everything is full with connections. Make it larger.

Electronically:

no sense in using a relay here, very likely.
an LM393 has an output that can only pull low, not high.
Even when sinking current, an LM393 can at most sink 20 mA. That's very likely much less than your relay needs.

So, you need to fix the comparator output.
But:
why use this complex contraption, anyways? Your sensor, a 2€ microcontroller, a decoupling capacitor, an NPN transistor + base resistor + LED + series resistor for the LED would totally do the job here – at a fraction of the complexity and cost of your analog circuitry, and with no parts that are likely to fail after a while, and without having to hope that an LM393.
No commercial entity or sensible hobbyist would try to build things this way; throwing the very "digital control" problem

I need to supervise an externally sensed condition, and based on that, do something with an LED

is really what microcontrollers have been invented for; it's what they are essentially application-specifically made integrated circuits for.
